# Export and view with lyx

Tags: lyx, preview, export

I have **control + R** for previewing pdf by command "**buffer-view**". I use **Alt+ R** to "**buffer-export**". I would like to **export and view** by combining thes two commands. I tried short-cuts CTR+R: `buffer-view; buffer-export` and other short-cut CTRL+R: `buffer-export-view.` These do not work. Kindly suggest

Comment: Does `command-sequence buffer-view; buffer-export` do what you want? It works for me on Linux.

Comment: @scottkosty It showed "invalid or unknown lyx function" error. I added it to short-cuts. Is there any other way to execute that I might be missing

Comment: First try executing it on the command buffer before making a shortcut. Go to View > Toolbars > Command buffer (or on Linux you can do `alt + x`. There will be a small text box that shows at the bottom of the screen. Enter the command there and press enter. Does that work? If not, what error does it give? If it does work, when we can move on to figuring out the shortcut.

Comment: @scottkosty Yes. it does work.

Comment: OK so the problem comes when adding it as a shortcut. What LyX version do you have? Can you please add a screen shot of the "Edit shortcut" dialog after you paste in the command. Note that the keyword `command-sequence` is part of the actual command.

Comment: I was adding it to CTRL+R and it was not working. When I added another shortcut key f12 instead of CTRL+R, it simply worked. Thanks. If you write it as answer, I can accept and up vote it.

Comment: Thanks for that information. Ah, I didn't realize the problem was specific to Ctrl + R. You would prefer to be able to use Ctrl + R right? Let's keep trying. Here it works for me. I do get a dialog that says "Shortcut Ctrl + R is already bound to buffer-view. Are you sure...". I then just have to click on "Redefine" and then it works for me. Do you get such a dialog? But when clicking on Redefine it still doesn't work?